# How do I hide the checkbox when there is no data coming from the API?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and this is the logic that I'm using for the checkbox. I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find anything useful. Is there any properties to hide the checkbox in the table body? Or have to implement logic in the ts file itself? let me know if it's properly implemented or I have done something wrong.

Ts:

```
 selection = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);

    get allSelected(): boolean {
        console.log(this.empdata);
        return this.selection.selected.length === this.empdata?.data.length;
      }
      toggleMasterSelection() {
        if (this.allSelected) {
          this.selection.clear();
        } else {
          this.selection.select(...this.empdata.data);
        }
      }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="empdata" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Checkbox">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox
              [checked]="allSelected"
              [indeterminate]="selection.selected.length !== 0 && !allSelected"
              (change)="toggleMasterSelection()"
            ></mat-checkbox>
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-checkbox
              [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
              (change)="selection.toggle(row)"
            ></mat-checkbox>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Report Name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Report Name</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            {{ row.ReportName }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Created On">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Created On</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.CreatedOn }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Created by">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Created By</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.CreatedBy }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Created For">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Created For</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.CreatedFor }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Export">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="align-header-right">
            <button id="selected-report" mat-flat-button>
              Export selected Report
            </button>
          </th>
          <td class="td-width" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <button id="see-report" mat-flat-button>See Report</button>
            <button id="export-report" mat-flat-button>Export Report</button>
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="4"
              height="17"
              viewBox="0 0 4 17"
            >
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="r31hsfo88a">
                  <path
                    data-name="Rectangle 279"
                    transform="translate(0 -1)"
                    style="fill: #77686a"
                    d="M0 0h4v17H0z"
                  />
                </clipPath>
              </defs>
              <g
                data-name="Group 321"
                transform="translate(0 1)"
                style="clip-path: url(#r31hsfo88a)"
              >
                <path
                  data-name="Path 381"
                  d="M3 4H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1"
                  transform="translate(0 -.494)"
                  style="fill: #77686a"
                />
                <path
                  data-name="Path 382"
                  d="M3 10H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1"
                  transform="translate(0 -.494)"
                  style="fill: #77686a"
                />
                <path
                  data-name="Path 383"
                  d="M3 16H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1"
                  transform="translate(0 -.494)"
                  style="fill: #77686a"
                />
              </g>
            </svg>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container>
          <tr style="text-align: center" *matNoDataRow>
            <td [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
              <app-no-data [imageSource]="'/assets/images/nosearchres.svg'">
              </app-no-data>
              Sorry! No search result found :(
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
      </table>
      <div *ngIf="!dataSource">
        <tr style="text-align: center">
          <td>
            <app-no-data [imageSource]="'/assets/images/nosavedreport.svg'">
            </app-no-data>
            No Saved Report
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: if you dont want it to show up when their is no data coming from api cant you use ngif condition ? to stop it from rendering?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna show / hide some element in HTML based on some condition use *ngIf directive.

```
 <mat-checkbox
   *ngIf="data.length"
   [checked]="allSelected"
   [indeterminate]="selection.selected.length !== 0 && !allSelected"
   (change)="toggleMasterSelection()"
 ></mat-checkbox>
```

In code above checkbox will be displayed only in case of NOT empty array

Official docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: beat me to it :)

Comment: I tried this a while ago but not working for me actually. The header checkbox is not showing when there is data showing in table.

Comment: *ngIf="empdata?.filteredData.length > 0"
this logic helped me fix the problem